# Problema con hora actual en PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Puesto que tengo varias columnas de fecha en la tabla y no puedo usar en más de una columna `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, a través de una función que he creado saco la fecha actual. La función es la siguiente:

```
function dame_fecha_actual() {
    $hoy = getdate();
    $meses = ['enero', 'febrero', 'marzo', 'abril', 'mayo', 'junio','julio','agosto','septiembre','octubre','noviembre','diciembre'];

    $minuto = $hoy['minutes'];
    $hora = $hoy['hours'];
    $day = $hoy['mday'];
    $mes = $hoy['mon'];
    $segundos = $hoy['seconds'];

    if ($hoy['hours'] <= 9) {
        $hora = "0" . $hoy['hours'];
    }

    if ($hoy['minutes'] <= 9) {
        $minuto = "0" . $hoy['minutes'];
    }

    if ($hoy['mon'] <= 9) {
        $mes = "0" . $hoy['mon'];
    }

    if ($hoy['mday'] <= 9) {
        $day = "0" . $hoy['mday'];
    }

    if ($hoy['seconds'] <= 9) {
        $segundos = "0" . $hoy['seconds'];
    }

    $fecha_total_actual = $hoy['year'] . "-" . $mes . "-" . $day . " " . $hora . ":" . $minuto . ":" . $segundos;

    return $fecha_total_actual; }
```

Me he dado cuenta que en local no me pasa, pero en la web a la hora de introducir la hora a la base de datos, me resta dos horas a la hora que realmente es aquí (vivo en España).

Por lo que se comenta en la página de PHP, la funcion [getdate()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.getdate.php) debería de darme la hora local actual si no añado `$timestamp`.

Comment: Chequeaste los timezones del php y del mysql ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Solucion - PHP

Aunque intento reproducir el error ha sido en vano, ya que tanto en php-cli, como en apache, arrojan la misma hora, hay algo que podrias tener en cuenta:

Existe una funcion en PHP, llamada [date_default_timezone_set()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.date-default-timezone-set.php), esta permite "configurar" una zona horaria, para tu programa.

**Como funciona?**

Basta simplemente agregar la funcion, indicando la zona horaria a usar:

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set("America/Los_Angeles");

function dame_fecha_actual() {
...
}
```

Lo que le indicamos al programa, es que use por defecto la zona horaria de "Los Angeles".

Lo cual en lugar de arrojar:

> 2017-07-05 23:20:45

Arrojara:

> 2017-07-05 21:20:53

Puedes encontrar en la documentacion de PHP un [listado de zonas horarias validas.](http://php.net/manual/es/timezones.php)

---

#### Solucion - Apache

Es una posibilidad que tengas desconfigurada la hora en el servidor de Apache. La solucion para este tipo de problema, es muy similar a la anterior:

1. Abrimos el archivo PHP.INI (/etc/php5/apache2/ en GNU/Linux).
2. Buscas la linea `date.timezone`.
3. Agregas la zona horaria, de acuerdo a la documentacion de PHP.

Debe pasar de:

```
date.timezone =
```

A quedar, (por ejemplo):

```
date.timezone = "America/Bogota"
```

Y bastaria reiniciar el Apache para que los cambios surgan efecto.

Comment: Me sirvió añadiendo la línea que comentabas. ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Con gusto, igual estoy agregando una solucion alternativa del lado de la configuracion del apache